# How do I bind each select option for each item in for loop? Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, html-select, v-for

So I have the following code in vue.js:

```html
<div v-for="guest in guests" :key="guest">
  <label for="attendance">Will  {{guest}}  be attending? </label>
    <select v-model="attendance">
      <option value="yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
</div>
```

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYVGe.png)

I want to know what each guest selects and send it to my backend. Guest is an array that gets sent from the previous page. Here is it's code:

```js
created() {
  this.guests = this.$route.query.guests;
  this.numGuests = this.guests.length;
},
```

Currently I am just sending each guest by sending this.guest but I am hoping to bind this somehow.
I have no idea how to do this and I do not know if I am searching for the right thing either. Hopefully someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could save it like an `object` like this

```js
   new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        guests: [
          'steve', 'mark', 'mario'
        ],
        attendance: {}
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="guest in guests" :key="guest">
    <label for="attendance">Will  {{guest}}  be attending? </label>
    <select v-model="attendance[guest]">
      <option value="yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>
    <br>
  </div>
  
  <h2>Attendace: {{ attendance }}</h2>
</div>
```